# Detect when users click on links in custom WebKit window

Tags: cocoa, webkit

In my OSX/Cocoa application, I'd like to detect when users are clicking on a link in my WebKit (WebView) view. I tried setting the UI delegate and implementing "webView:createWebViewWithRequest" however, the request object is ALWAYS nil when this method is called.

The link used is valid. When used with an external web browser it will lead to a valid page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to make a [WebPolicyDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/PolicyDecisions.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001496-CJBEHAAG) and implement the `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` and `decidePolicyForNewWindowAction` methods.